# Javascript: Event in iFrame

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I'm building a `WYISWYG` editor with an `iframe` with `designMode = 'on'`.

The problem is that I can't use any event on the iframe in Firefox and Opera (IE untested), for example I would like to track the onkeyup event:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").onkeyup = function(){
    doSomething...
}
```

But doesn't works in the parent window.

I tried in the iframe too with this:

```
top.frames[0].onkeyup = function(){
        doSomething...
}
```

and all kind of stuff like these:

```
top.document.frames[0].onkeyup
top.frames["myFrame"].onkeyup
top.frames[0].document.onkeyup
```

But none of them wants to work so at the end turned out that even `window.onclick` doesn't works, so now I'm a bit confused...

What's the solution for this?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be with `document.designMode = "on"` in the iframe

Comment: Is your iframe on a different domain? Can you post a http://JSFiddle.net example?

Comment: No it's not on a different domain, It has a source but both files are on localhost. How should I post an example there if there is no way to add another HTML file as the iframe source?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest catching the event on the iframe's `Document`, and in Firefox at least you need to do this using `addEventListener()` rather than `onkeyup`. The following will work in all major browsers:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

function handleIframeKeyUp(evt) {
    alert("Key up!");
}

if (typeof iframeDoc.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    iframeDoc.addEventListener("keyup", handleIframeKeyUp, false);
} else if (typeof iframeDoc.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    iframeDoc.attachEvent("onkeyup", handleIframeKeyUp);
}
```

Comment: This works with click, keyup etc but not focus or blur. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick: `focus` and `blur` don't bubble and don't fire on the document. It may work on the iframe element itself or its window (`iframe.contentWindow`).

Comment: I found that it worked in Firefox, but Safari and Chrome wouldn't respond to blur/focus events on the iframe element itself, I had to bind those events to the body element within the iframe.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Had the exact issue, trying to catch the event on the document, which works fine in Chrome. Now I just use  `$($editor.contentWindow).blur(function () {
    // code goes here
});` for all browsers